# Why in the following c statement, num value can be changed

Tags: c, string, types, type-conversion, integer

```
result[0] = (num % base) + '0';
```

When num was an even number before this statement, num becomes 48 after the above statement.
When num was a odd number before this statement, num becomes 49 after the above statement.

Comment: First use correct array index. you must use `0` zero instead of `o`. Second ASCII code for `0` is 48.

Comment: If the `base==2` result will hold 48 if num is even and 49 if odd.

Comment: Post how you determined the value of `num`.

Comment: What do you man by "num value can be changed"? What makes you think that it happens? I bet that if `num` where `const` the code would also work the same way, did you try?

Answer (score 0):

`result[0] = (num % base) + '0';`

The ASCII code of `'0'` is 48. If your number id even and `base == 2` the result of `num % base` will be zero. `48 + 0 == 48`. If your number is odd and `base == 2` the result of `num % base` is `1`. `48 + 1 == 49`. 49 in ASCII is `'1'`

https://godbolt.org/z/5VuFro